# README before start your Compiler project

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-development

Basically, it's a dream first ... *I might have my own programming language someday!*, but it will turn to a nightmare soon, just right after you looking for *How to build a compiler?*.

I spend too much time, like most of you guys, to read dragon books plus lots of other articles, resources, forums, and Q&A. What I finally came up with that was a mass of knowing lots of unnecessary things like *All the major parsing thechniques* or even *Compiler Optimisation* but still haven't a clear understanding of what I need to do finally with my compiler project.

The problem is in all of the books and other resources you need to understand (and master) the whole thing at once and at the beginning! You need to understand and implement the parser, while you still don't know what you're supposed to do next. By the way, I assume that you're a real beginner in this topic, however I know that it wasn't the case for some you.

Someday I stop reading those materials. I said it's enough to learning about every details, I want to do something real. So, I start asking questions like this: *What is the goal of a compiler?* Well, my answer was *Generating understandable binary code for the processor.* So, I said *How it should be then?* Well, something like this `statement1; statement2;` to `0xAABBCCDD`, and that's all.

Then I start everything from scratch. I start with the simplest syntax and machine codes. What I had at the end of the day was a working compiler which was able to generate pure binary code for Intel. It understands only a few instructions, but it was a real working compiler, however a very simple one.

Later I improved the parser, etc. and I felt much happier since that time. Now, I'm using all of these materials when I need them. My problem was I was trying so hard to understand and master everything, because I thought (mostly others said) that I can't make a compiler, even a simple one, without reading all of these books and articles.

Here, I'd like to ask you list the ideas and concepts which you think is necessary to know before starting any compiler projects. The things you believe they are *Simple* enough for a beginner to read and understand, to picture the whole project better, and to move on to writing the actual code and feel how does a real compiler work.

As an example see my answer here!

P.S. By the way, before you down vote the question, let me clear again that I'm not saying these materials are not good. I'm just saying the subject is incredibly vague. The wrong approach is to go for everything at once. The smarter solution is start with a *Hello World!* example, instead of a project with the same features as GCC, etc.

Comment: By the time your compiler can compile 'Hello World' you already have almost all of the scanner built, a good bit of the parser, and quite a bit of the code generator. There is most certainly nothing vague about compiler construction, it's just a very large and very well-researched part of IT, possibly the most researched after the hardware. Your methodology doesn't really make sense, and this is not a real question.

Comment: @EJP how we learn a new programming language? by a Hello World program, right? We don't study how to make a huge software at first. We should do the same for compiler projects, that's what I meant not making a hello world application by our compiler ...

Comment: It's not how I learned it. I studied screening, scanning, parsing, symbol tables, name tables, semantic analysis, code generation, register allocation, and linking, and I've probably left a few things out. We were given an existing parser and asked to modify it in small ways. Compilers themselves aren't all that huge, but there's a lot to learn. There is certainly no such thing as a 'Hello World!' compiler. The closest thing to that might be a recursive descent expression parser.

Comment: Asking for a "list of ideas and concepts" is not constructive and does not fit the Q&A style of this site.

Comment: @AustinHenley thanks, I agree with you, however I don't know how to rephrase that. If any of you guys can change it to a better format, feel free to edit it up. BTW, I think the question by itself could be useful for others, even if nobody use that, however I agree that it's not enough constructive as it should be ...

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing is to understand how does a *Processor* works. You need to choose a particular target at first, but you can obviously extend it later.Manufacturer's documentation will helps you so much, as well.

**Warm up videos**

1. [Introduction to CPUs @ Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaui8sPWEx4)
2. [How does a CPU work @ Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBnMCe0Du6o) demo via [MSX88](http://msx88.diatel.upm.es/)
3. [CPU Registers @ Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBThj0ZyldE)
4. [CPU Registers @ Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mqv4lXYY4VU)
5. [8086 Register Set @ Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoh9HB-CJPo)
6. [x64 Register Set @ Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4jEBxSOSuk)
7. [How Computers Add Numbers @ Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBDoT8o4q00)
8. [FLAGS Register @ Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ragCcJRJFs)
9. [System Organization: CPU-RAM-I/O @ Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ECNMxZBLa0)
10. Not in English, but worth to have a look: [CPU Builder @ Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/user/theCpuBuilder?feature=watch)

**Articles**

1. [What does a CPU do @ eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how-does_4914716_what-does-cpu-do.html)
2. [How a CPU Works @ Hardware Secrets](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/209)

**Hardware Manuals**

1. [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)
2. [AMD Developer Guides and Manuals](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/developer-guides-manuals/)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the most important thing. You need to understand a lot of things, and they are all equally important.

Comment: @EJP I'd still say this is the most important thing, as this is the most important thing in a computer as well. There are other important things you need to know, I agree with that, but they're are not equally important IMHO.

Comment: @Fooyd It is meaningless to single out one thing as more important when they are all essential.

Answer (score 0):

The [flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Simple-Examples.html) and [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples) manuals give some very simple examples for writing a basic interpreter:

I can access both on my local machine with the "info flex" and "info bison" commands, respectively.

EDIT: Just saw and thought I would share this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15743032/1003855