# simple compiler for optimization purposes

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I want a source code of a simple compiler to optimize by interchanging the code for delayed branches for my assignment.

I read the [is there a simple compiler for a small language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913621/is-there-a-simple-compiler-for-a-small-language) question and found several good compilers.

But optimization has done for almost all of them and some links are dead. Can someone recommend me a simple compiler for a small language that is not implemented optimization for delayed branches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try: [cucu: a compiler you can understand](http://zserge.com/blog/cucu-part1.html)

It is a simple C compiler, less than 700 lines of code.  I found it well written and easy to follow.